# How is this a valid answer when converting boolean value to a string

Tags: python-3.x, function

we have a function *bool_to_string(flag)* and you're supposed to define it so that the bool value passed to the function *i.e flag* is always returned as a string.

```
bool_to_string = str
```

This was a valid answer but I don't understand how it works. I know about lambda but this doesn't appear to be that. Can someone explain to me how it is so short?

edit: like the person below highlighted, our original function was just converting a value to string. That is the same the built-in function str() does so we have just swapped out our original function with str. Simple and clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

The expression creates a new function `bool_to_string` and assigns it the value of function `str`. In essence, `bool_to_string` is an alias for the `str` function.

In Python, everything is an object you can work with functions in the same way as with any other data type.

Comment: That is absolutely clever and beautiful. I'm glad I didn't back out of asking the question as it felt a little stupid. Thanks friend!